# Including a native C++ header from C++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, c++-cli

I'm just experimenting with mixing a native C++ (that uses MFC) static lib and a C++/CLI WinForms application. When I try to include my NativeClass.h, compiling the C++/CLI app fails because it doesn't understand `AFX_EXT_CLASS` used to export the class for the lib.

Just to get it working, I was able to build the native lib, then remove the `AFX_EXT_CLASS` from the header, then build the C++/CLI linked to the native lib. The C++/CLI app will run, the dialog comes up and outputs some dummy value from my NativeClass::NativeFunction() method. Everything seems to work great, except I can't build the C++/CLI app without removing `AFX_EXT_CLASS`. Any ideas how to make this work without having to edit the header? I would prefer a single step build.

```
// NativeClass.h
class AFX_EXT_CLASS NativeClass {
    public:
        NativeClass();
        ~NativeClass();

        int NativeFunction();
};
```

This is the error I get when building the C++/CLI app while `AFX_EXT_CLASS` is in the header:

```
NativeClass.h(3): error C2470: 'NativeClass' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it compiled and running by adding `#define AFX_EXT_CLASS` to my C++/CLI app's stdafx.h. I figured since the C++/CLI app isn't really concerned with the macro, there's no need for it to worry, so defining it makes the compiler happy and doesn't seem to cause any ill effects.

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting a great diagnostic from the compiler, the simple problem is that it doesn't know what AFX_EXT_CLASS means.  Don't leave it off, the macro expands to __declspec(dllimport).  Simply fix your problem by #including `<afx.h>`.  The shared version of the MFC library is required, it will complain if you forget to select it.

Comment: Do I #include <afx.h> from the native lib or the C++/CLI app?

Comment: Your native lib's source code already has it if it uses MFC.  It needs to be added to your C++/CLI source code.  Put it before the #include for the lib's header file.

Comment: Makes sense. I added the include and it builds, but when I attempt to run, I get a debug assertion (before it even enters my main() ) upon calling _crtIsValidHeapPtr().

I tried something else and got it working though, see my posted answer to this question. If you see any problems with my answer, I'd appreciate your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the qualifier on that class. Since your class doesn't inherit from anything it isn't necessary. The managed C++/CLI compiler can compile native classes under #pragma managed and yet not require these native classes to have any special modifiers on them.

Also I would beware of thinking that MFC is the entire C++ world.... it isn't. Lots of people, including myself, compile lots of native C++ classes with the /clr switch turned on, and we have never used this weird AFX_EXT_CLASS macro.

So it might be good to try a little stand alone project that contains just this class (without the macro) and doesn't depend on MFC at all. Then make that compile with managed C++/CLI. Once you get it working, then add functionality to the class bit by bit until you get it working how you like it. Finally I think you will see that MFC probably has some baggage you must jettison to work with /clr successfully.

Comment: I'm building this experiment as a proof of concept for an existing project. We have nearly 2 million lines of native C++ code built into libraries that all use AFX_EXT_CLASS to export the class to the dlls/libs. My proof of concept must work with the AFX_EXT_CLASS macro, otherwise the concept won't work with our code.

Answer (score 0):

> Just to get it working,

Here is the diagram that will help you know how CLR executes Native C++ code: 
[image]